# LINQ to query Service Fabric Reliable Collections?

Tags: linq, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

Are there any plans in adding LINQ support for Reliable Collections on Service Fabric? Does anyone know of any extensions that can enable this? It seems like this was possible in a previous API version but not anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a reliable dictionary, you can use `CreateEnumerableAsync` to create an async enumerable. (Documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.data.collections.ireliabledictionary-2.createenumerableasync?view=azure-dotnet).)

Next, you can create linq queries by using Eli's extension methods [here](https://gist.github.com/aelij/987d974c811865029564f1bbeffb6b47).

Example from gist:

```
var accounts = await (await accountNames.CreateLinqAsyncEnumerable(txn))
                .Where(x => x.Value.IndexOf(name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                .SelectAsync(async x => new Account
                {
                    Id = x.Key,
                    Name = x.Value,
                    Data = (await accountData.TryGetValueAsync(txn, x.Key)).Value
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: What's the performance of this? Is the enumeration only taking place on the subset of data fullfilling the range, or is everything pulled in memory and is enumeration happening on the full collection?

Comment: Also would like to know answer of the above comment. I will have rather large collections where I only need to grab a subset of records, if this pulls the entire collection into memory its a no go.

Comment: I believe the above code would have every value in memory at some point, but if the value is not projected, it will become eligible to be paged out (again). This code can be optimized by using indices and/or key filters.